# spritekit SKAction.resizeToHeight is not repeating

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to increase the height of in touch events, it's same like stick hero is doing. I am trying following code

```
      func changeHeight(){


    let action = SKAction.resizeToHeight(self.leadherNode!.size.height+50, duration: 0.5);
    let seq = SKAction.repeatActionForever(action)
    self.leadherNode?.runAction(seq, withKey: "height")


}
```

but unfortunately it just increase the height of node for first time and it never repeats. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you need a sequence where you set the size back to the original size, otherwise repeat resizes will not make the node larger but rather resize it to the same size the node already has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to an argument of an `SKAction` after it has started will have no effect on the action. You will need to create a new action with the updated value at each step. Here's one way to do that:

Define and initialize the height and max height properties

```
var spriteHeight:CGFloat = 50.0;
let maxHeight:CGFloat = 500.0
```

Call this from `didMoveToView`

```
resizeToHeight()
```

This function creates an `SKAction` that resizes a sprite to a specific height. After the completion of the action, the function updates the height value and then calls itself.

```
func resizeToHeight() {
   self.leadherNode?.runAction(
        SKAction.resizeToHeight(self.spriteHeight, duration: 0.5),
        completion:{
            // Run only after the previous action has completed
            self.spriteHeight += 50.0
            if (self.spriteHeight <= self.maxHeight) {
                self.resizeToHeight()
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know swift. But I can write objective-c version.

```
CGFloat currentSpriteSize;//Create private float
SKSpriteNode *sprite;//Create private sprite

currentSpriteSize = sprite.size.height;//Into your start method

//And your Action
SKAction *seq = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction runBlock:^{
        currentSpriteSize += 50;
    }], [SKAction resizeToHeight:currentSpriteSize duration:0.5]]];
    [sprite runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:seq]];
```